# Update table with values from a form on the same page

Tags: php, html, mysql

This is the code of my homepage:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>PHP test</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>


<div id="formDiv">  
    <form action="testsql.php" method="post">
        Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
        <textarea name="comment" rows="10" cols="40">Your comment here.</textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>


<div id="show">         
<?php

    $con=mysqli_connect("","root","","my_db");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Comments");

    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Comment</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Email'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['comment'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the code of the testsql.php file:

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("","root","","my_db");

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{ 

header("Location: testphp.php");
if(empty($_POST["comment"]))
    {echo "You have to write something. <br>";}

else
    {
      if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        if(empty($_POST["email"]))
        {
            $sql="INSERT INTO Comments (Email, comment)
            VALUES
            ('$_POST[email]', '$_POST[comment]')";
            echo "1 record added.";
            if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
                {
                    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
                }

        }
        else{
            if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$_POST["email"]))
            {
                echo "Invalid email format <br>"; 
            }
        else{
            echo "Your email is: {$_POST["email"]} <br>";
            $sql="INSERT INTO Comments (Email, comment)
            VALUES
            ('$_POST[email]', '$_POST[comment]')";
            echo "1 record added.";
            if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
                {
                    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
                }

            }
        }
    }
   }
 ?>
```

What I want to do is to take the values from the form and put them in the table. The table should be updated after I click the submit button. It works when I have the `header(Location: "testphp.php");` but then it won't show the error messages if the user writes his mail the wrong way or doesn't write a comment.

When I don't include the header the code works right but I get redirected to *testsql.php* and I have to go back to *testphp.php* to see the updated table. I know that I can use javascript but our professor told us that the **site should be fully usable with javascript turned off**. Any ideas?

Comment: You're using your `header("Location: testphp.php");` prematurely. Of course if the request is `POST` it has done its job. You need to place `header("Location: testphp.php");` "after" it has successfully queried your DB.

Comment: I've tried putting header after getting the values but I get a warning of this type. Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /some/file.php:12) in /some/file.php on line 23

Comment: Are you using sessions by any chance?

Comment: No, this is my first time using php.

Comment: Then you either may have a whitespace before any `<?php` or a byte order mark issue, or some other type of output.

Comment: Plus, instead of doing `{echo "You have to write something. <br>";}` use `die()` I.e.: `{die("You have to write something.");}` or put an `exit();` I.e.: `{echo "You have to write something. <br>"; exit();}` if you want to show the user an error message. It will only continue through the script if there is no exit.

Comment: I don't have any whitespace before the <?php. I also changed the die to the way you told me. Isn't there a way to send the value to a php file, add it to the database and then be redirected to the page with the form and table?

Comment: I suggest you redirect it back to your homepage instead, since you're already querying it there.

Comment: Try using your redirect in place of `echo "1 record added.";` and get rid of (or comment out) that line `echo "1 record added.";` If a header redirect still gives you problems, use a meta refresh equivalent.

Comment: How do I redirect it to the page testphp.php file? I added the echo just to see if it gets into the if statement, I will delete it after I  figure the problem out.

Comment: Have you tried `header(Location: "testphp.php");` in place of the `echo "1 record added.";`? Theoretically, it should go there, IF the query was successful. And what is the `testphp.php` file, your homepage?

Comment: I've tried it and I get the warning mentioned before. Yes it is my homepage. I'm just trying to work things out on the testphp.php file before I add it to my real homepage

Comment: Then try using `echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"2;URL=testphp.php\">";` that should work.

Comment: Yes, this seems to work. But I get redirected to another page where I get a message. For example "Invalid email" and then I'm being sent back. Is there a way to have the message being shown on the same page or am I asking to much? What if I put the whole code in the "testphp.php" file?

Comment: I'm curious. Is your Entire code inside one page (form and SQL insert) ? Are you using any type of include above your `testsql.php` page? `headers already sent` error message is only caused if there is anything above `<?php` in your `testsql.php` file.

Comment: The only way(s) of having messages shown on the same page, is if you use the ENTIRE code inside one big clump, and using `<form action="" method="post">` --- `action=""` is equivalent to `self` (same page). Or, use AJAX. That's the best I can say.

Comment: Yes form and SQL insert is on the same page. I also added the code of the other file to the testphp.php file and everything is working as I wanted,though I don't know if it is good programming...

Comment: It could stand to be reformatted and rethought, but if it works for the moment, good. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need use **Ajax** aproach with JavaScript.

See [DataTable](http://www.datatables.net/) plugin for JQuery to do it easy.

Comment: Professor told us JavaScript should be turned off :P

Comment: You should use **<iframe>**

Comment: Who is going to refresh the iframe once form has been submitted?